# adding part of a row as a new row to the table

Tags: jquery, html

There is a table with a link that adds a new row when clicked:

```
    <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">col1</th>
                    <th scope="col">col2</th>
                    <th scope="col">col3</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input name="col1" id="col1"></td>
                    <td><input name="col2" id="col2"></td>
                    <td>
                      <select name="col3" id="col3">
                        <option value="">Please select</option>
                        <option value="1">select1</option>
                        <option value="2">select1</option>
                        <option value="3">select1</option>
                      </select>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
<a href="#" id="addLink">+</a>
```

when the link is clicked, I want to add a new row but without the 3rd column to the end of the table. so I used JQuery to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#addLink').click(function(){
                    addTableRow($("table"));
                    return false;
                }); // end click
            function addTableRow(table)
            {
                // get the first row in the table
                var $tr = $(table).find("tbody tr:first").html();

                $($tr).remove('td:last'); // remove the last column 


                $('tbody').append("<tr>");
                $(table).find('tbody tr:last').append($tr);


                        };
            }); // end ready
```

however, this part is not removing the 3rd column:

```
$($tr).remove('td:last'); // remove the last column
```

is there any way to append a new row with just the first 2 column?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @max4ever this one is not working ...

Comment: Did you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dktqs/?

Comment: @j08691 but clone() will copy all the values in the fields to the new row

Comment: true, but emptying them is trivial. Is the functionality what you wanted?

Comment: @j08691 how to empty input's field?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dktqs/1/

Comment: @j08691 but what if the 2nd column is <select> instead of <input>? so you have to modify the code to $('select',$tr).val('');?

Comment: Yes, but that's trivial too. However it seems you already accepted an answer so I guess there's no need to take this any further :)

Comment: @j08691 the answer i took does not depend on the column type. thx though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

i changed a few other things as well, you'll get the idea.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#addLink').click(function(){
    addTableRow($("table"));
    return false;
  }); // end click
  function addTableRow(table) {
    // get the first row in the table
    var $tr = table.find("tbody tr:first").html();


    $('tbody').append($('<tr/>'));
    table.find('tbody tr:last').append($tr).find('td:last').remove();


  };
}); // end ready​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QTuzM/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `html` method:

```
$(table).find("tbody tr:first td:last").remove();
```

Comment: thx. I added this line after my last line: "$(table).find('tbody tr:last td:last').remove();" and it works :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    $('tbody').append("<tr>");
                $(table).find('tbody tr:last').append($tr);
???
```

how about

```
$(table).find('tbody').append($tr)
```

Comment: but the point is the remove() function is not removing the 3rd column